# pyqt5 QLineEdit.setText only work once in funcion when I hope do somthing between two setText

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize , QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from pytube import YouTube
import os
import time
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 200))    
        self.setWindowTitle("下載影片程式") 

        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('網址:')
        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line.move(80, 20)
        self.line.resize(500, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)

        pybutton = QPushButton('下載', self)
#        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.Download)
#        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.Download1)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 60)        

        self.statusline = QLineEdit(self)
        self.statusline.move(80, 100)
        self.statusline.resize(200, 32)

#        self.statusline1 = QLineEdit(self)
#        self.statusline1.move(80, 140)
#        self.statusline1.resize(200, 32)
#        
    def clickMethod(self):
        print('')
    def Download(self):
        self.statusline.setText('開始下載')
        if not os.path.isdir('D:\\下載影片'):
            os.mkdir('D:\\下載影片')
        yt = YouTube(self.line.text())



        video=yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').first()
        video.download(r'D:\\下載影片')
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.statusline.setText('下載完成'))

#    def Download1(self):
#        self.statusline.setText('下載完成')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

I want to it show 'start' before download youtube then show 'finsh' .

But it always only show 'finsh'.

Why the  QLineEdit only show 'finsh' when I click the  QPushButton?

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante  I edit my full code,thanks

Comment: The MRE should not depend on an external link since they can be broken making it unusable for future readers so the MRE must be in your question. I've taken the job of copying it, do you agree?

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 1):

The task of downloading a file can take a long time so it blocks the event loop causing the GUI to freeze, and the effect of freezing is that the GUI is not updated correctly.

Considering the above, the solution is to execute the download on another thread.

```py
import functools
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject, QSize, QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFormLayout,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy,
    QWidget,
)

from pytube import YouTube


class DownloadWorker(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def download(self, url, path):
        self.started.emit()
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
        try:
            yt = YouTube(url)
            video = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4").first()
            video.download(path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        self.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 200))
        self.setWindowTitle("Download Video Program")

        self.line = QLineEdit()
        self.pybutton = QPushButton("download")
        self.pybutton.setFixedSize(200, 32)
        self.statusline = QLineEdit()
        self.statusline.setFixedSize(200, 32)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QFormLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addRow("URL:", self.line)
        lay.addRow("", self.pybutton)
        lay.addRow("", self.statusline)

        thread = QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self.worker = DownloadWorker()
        self.worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)

    def download(self):
        url = self.line.text()
        # TODO
        path = "/path/of/output.mp4"
        wrapper = functools.partial(self.worker.download, url, path)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        self.statusline.setText("Started")
        self.pybutton.setEnabled(False)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.statusline.setText("Finished")
        self.pybutton.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```